# 502 Bad Gateway error for Flask app hosted on Microsoft Azure with specific app route

Tags: python, azure, flask, twilio

I am trying to host a web app on Microsoft Azure. The app is for a chatbot and is coded in Python using Flask and Twilio. When viewing the web page online - @app.route('/') - it displays correctly. But when sending a message through Twilio - @app.route('/bot', methods = ['GET', 'POST']) - it returns a 502 error. Nothing shows in the Azure application logs.

```
# tester to see response
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello world!"

# actual bot logic
@app.route('/bot', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bot():
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    # bot logic
    return str(resp)
```

I should note that, when running off PythonAnywhere or a local host, it all works as expected. The error message from Twilio is

> Twilio was unable to fetch content from: http://gbot->initial.azurewebsites.net/bot
>
> Error: Total timeout is triggered. Configured tt is 15000ms and we attempted 1 time(s)
>
> Remote Host: gbot-initial.azurewebsites.net
>
> Request Method: POST
>
> Request URI: http://gbot-initial.azurewebsites.net/bot
>
> URL Fragment: true

I have exhausted my resources and would appreciate any help on the matter.

Comment: No way we can help here without seeing your code, seeing your API call to Twilio, and without seeing any other specific messages that come along with your Bad Gateway error.

Comment: I assumed since its a 502 error the problem is on the server side but I will get the code snippets for you

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be my database connection. I don't expect this to be the end of all my woes but it is for now. Thanks for the help.